# 2008 Ford escape hybrid blend door actuator

Tags: ford, hvac, escape, hybrid

I have a similar issue, my 2008 ford escape hybrid driver side remains on cold and my passenger side climate control works fine, no problems. I also notice that when I turn the knob on the driver side to heat, it does display on my dash that its changing the temp because it will say 90 degrees but doesn't change the temp. So I do believe its my driver side blend door actuator. Am I correct? and can I really replace it by only removing the glove department door?

Comment: HAd the same problem on my 2001 Escape except the blend door stuck on hot not cold. Turned out to be a dodgy connection from the wiring loom connector into the actuator receptacle. Before replacing the the actuator (even though it is a low cost item) try wiggling the connections. If that doesn't work it will be the actuator itself, but even then the whole thing may not need replacing. The small DC motor inside it is often the culprit and these can be bought for a few (around $5.00)dollars and are easy to replace. However paying $27 for a new assembly may well be better than waiting for the rig

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what I'd say the issue is ... most vehicles today have blend door actuators which are operated with an electric motor. These motors can go bad without regard to your comfort. In most cases the actuators are pretty easy to get to, though I don't know exactly where it's at with your specific vehicle. You will most likely find it on the driver's side of the vehicle. Engineers seem to place them where you can readily get to them. When you find it, you can try actuating it with a 12v source to see if it's working or not. It should look something like this:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I called the Ford dealer and the cost was $682.00 to replace. But when I saw the utube video on how to replace it, it seemed fairly simple except I would need a tool that my brother has and the part is only $27.00 at autozone. So I will attempt to replace on my own. My concern was that I read there is 3 different actuators. but I believe its the temperature regulator and looks like the picture you sent. Thank you again. Im a girl who doesn't mind getting her hands dirty. So Im gonna give it a whirl.

Comment: I love girls who get their hands dirty! It shouldn't be too difficult to replace the actuator, just test the old one before you purchase a new one to make sure you have the right one.